# How to use index in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I use three columns from the data frame for indexing:

```
df = df.set_index(['col1','col2','col3'])
```

Then I try to get the row that corresponds to a particular index. I tried many different ways:

```
x = df.loc[(123,456,789)]

x = df.ix[(123,456,789)]

x = df.loc[123,456,789]

x = df.ix[123,456,789]
```

None of these options works. The error message that I get is:

```
raise e1
KeyError: 'MultiIndex lexsort depth 0, key was length 3'
```

I checked if the used value of index exists:

```
inds = []
for ind in df.index:
    inds.append(ind)

if (123,456,789) in inds:
    print 'in'
else:
    print 'out'
```

As the result I get `in` (so, this used value of index exists). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you sort the df, all your loc/ix methods should work.

```
df = df.set_index(['col1','col2','col3'])
df.sort(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Should I sort the data frame before or after the indexing? How exactly should I sort it (what column should I use for sorting)?

Comment: After setting the index, sort the dataframe using index like above. Sorting will make `MultiIndex lexsort depth` (in the error message) from 0 to 3.